# Reload Div automaticly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div on my .php site which contains some content. Now, I want the Div to refresh itself after every 5 seconds by a script on the same page.

I already tried to do this by JQuery, but all examples given just showed how to load and refresh content from another file.

Whats the most simple way to solve this? (Maybe with JS?)

At the Moment I'm struggeling with this:

```js
function autoRefresh_div() {
  $("#div").load("load.html", function() {
    setTimeout(autoRefresh_div, 5000);
  });
}

autoRefresh_div();
```

Comment: What  you have tried so far? please show your code as well

Comment: you will need some file/api/url to give you the new data you want to show, then use `setInterval`.  Post some code if you would like more assistance.

Comment: What does _refresh itself_ mean in this context? Does the element display some value from a database?

Comment: Try `$("div").load("load.html #div", function` to load only that element from the requested resource. Note however that this approach loads the _entire document_ for the purposes of displaying a very small fragment. Not ideal. If you have the ability to serve this content alone, from another endpoint, that would be much better.

Comment: Yes it does contain data from a Database. Refresh itself means it should be the only element on the page, which reload its content.

Comment: @E.Reutlinger you will want to be using `setInterval` not `setTimeout` since interval continually runs on the interval specified and timeout happens 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you're taking should work, with a couple small changes:

```
// Look-up this element once; not for each request
let element = document.getElementById("div");

function autoRefresh_div() {
    // Add a selector to jQuery.fn.load
    $(element).load("load.html #div", function() {
        setTimeout(autoRefresh_div, 5000);
    });
}

autoRefresh_div();
```

One thing to keep in mind is that the `$.fn.load` method requests the *entire document*, which could be fairly large. It then discards all of this, saving only the element you wish to display. This is a bit wasteful, especially for users who have to watch their data usage.

If the element displays a value from your database, I'd encourage you to construct some primitive REST API that allows you to retrieve that value alone. You can then request it alone with any of jQuery's AJAX methods.